# How to remove elements of csv file using rdd in scala?

Tags: scala, rdd

How to remove elements of CSV file using RDD in Scala?

```
val textRDD = sc.textFile("file:/home/bharathi/bhaskar/sample.tab")
```

I have values in the `sample.tab` like this

```
A   B   C   D
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
```

I have to delete the second row and show the output

Comment: I think the best approach could be to `filter` the data of the second row from the `RDD`, using some useful condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your second row is `5 6 7 8`, and you don't have any blank lines between your rows. You can use `zipWithIndex` to assign index to each row and then filter out the row that you don't want based on the index.

```
textRDD.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 != 2).map(_._1).foreach(println)
```

It will print

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
9 10 11 12
```